# Creating a custom alert in a form using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a custom alert message in a Google Form, the idea is that once the user submits the form it should show a message displaying a result based on what the user inputs on the form.
I've tried to use `Browser.msgBox()` and `getUi().alert()` but they seem to only work in spreadsheets. 
Is there any way to achieve this inside a form?

Comment: What kind of form Google Form or html form?

Comment: You can't do this with [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/).

Comment: Thats what I thought. Im gonna have to find a other way then. Thank you

Comment: @Frippie did you find another way?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*This can not be done in Google Forms.*

#### More Information:

According to Google's documentation on Simple and Installable triggers:

> The open event for Google Forms does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it.

If attempting to run the `FormApp.getUi()` method on an installable trigger on Form Submit, the following error appears in the Stackdriver logs under `My Executions`:

> Error: Cannot call `FormApp.getUi()` from this context. at onSumbit(Code:2)

So unfortunately, this can not be completed.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Google Apps Script - Class `Ui`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)