# Opening link (.setopenlink) onSubmit of google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am very new to google app scripts, I did this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J93uww0vMFY) to add geo tag info to a submission.

What I'd like to do now is something like making the submit button open the link so an additional click wasn't necessary.

Thinking an onSubmit type of thing.

Also I'm so new I dont know how to add this over, next to or in addition to the existing script.

Comment: I am not going to watch a video to figure out what you did.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> What I'd like to do now is something like making the submit button open the link so an additional click wasn't necessary.

On Google Forms the submit button can't be customized. If you really need to have custom action other than what an installable trigger can do when a form response is submitted you have to use another tool, i.e. you might use Google App Script to create a web application. For details about using Google Apps Script to create a web app see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.

Just in case that you are not familiar with the form submit installable triggers, there are two, one for the form and other for spreadsheet linked to the form, both are only able to get the corresponding form submit event object. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Related

- [Display custom message after submitting a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31644520/1595451)
- [Creating a custom alert in a form using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59565839/1595451)